# extrema(max-min) two variable constrained function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ with "fixed" Hessian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I have this function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ under the constrain : $x^6+3y^2=1$

I use the Lagrange multiplier method :

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
2x=6x^5\lambda\\
2y=6y\lambda\\
x^6+3y^2-1=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

We can easily get the points : $(\pm 1,0),(0,\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$

**Question** : How do I evaluate if a point is max or min ? if the hessian matrix is "fixed" like so :

$$H=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0  \\
    0 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

The determinant is always positive. We can even see both positive eigenvalues. But that does not mean that every point is a minimum! (right ?)

The only thing I can possibly think is to plug the points into the function, and check how is greater or not.

$f(\pm 1,0)=1$

$f(0,\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})=\frac{1}{3}$

So Just with intuition $1$ si greater than $\frac{1}{3}$ so $(\pm 1,0)$ are points of maximum; and so $(0,\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ are points of minimum.

But How do I know this is the right reasoning? Like, if I had found $4$ critical points how would I classified them? Are there other methods which I can apply?

Comment: Examining the Hessian of the unconstrained $f$ isn’t going to tell you much. Critical points of the Lagrangian generally don’t necessarily coincide with critical points of the unconstrained objective function. You need to examine the behavior of $f$ in directions consistent with the constraint function.

Answer (score 1):

Since the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x^6+3x^2=1\}$ is compact, $f$ must have a maximum and a minimum there. And it must be attained at some of the points that you got. So:

- the maximum is $1$ and it is attained at $(\pm1,0)$;
- the minimum is $\frac13$ and it is attained at $\left(0,\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)$.

Comment: What If I had more critical points ? How can I classify them ? Let's suppose I found $3$ critical points for a function $f(x,y)=something$ --> $(0,1)=2$,$(1,1)=4$,$(2,1)=8$ . (with fixed hessian) I can say that $(0,1)$ is a minimum and $(2,1)$ si a maximum; but what about $(1,1)$ ?

Comment: Forget the Hessian; it is not relevant here. If you have several critical points, you compute $f$ at each of them. Then the maximum of $f$ is the largest point that you get, whereas the mnimum of $f$ is the smallest one.

Comment: How do I know the nature of $(1,1)$ in the example above? I know how to get absolute max or min, but what about what's in between ?

Comment: In the example above, $f$ neither attains its maximum value nor its minimum value at $(1,1)$.

Comment: so $(1,1)$ might be a saddle point ?

Comment: No. Saddle points are not defined for functions defined on lines.